# My IDE keeps crashing instantly: How do I diagnose?

Tags: java, process, crash, debugging

I am using Aptana, Java-based IDE. Starting today, it is crashing suddenly every few minutes.

This may have to do with the fact that I recently upgraded to Xubuntu 14.04.

There is no error message. It just disappears instantly.  How can I diagnose this given that there is no error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nicer ways for sure; a simple approach however would be starting your application from terminal. There you see the output even after it has crashed.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. What are some of the "nicer" ways?

Comment: log files of the application, but I don't know where they are for yours - maybe sb else will

Comment: Thank you!  I got info on a core dump this way. Running from terminal is what I needed. This will help me formulate my question.

Comment: With the debug info in hand, it turned out to be a known problem when upgrading to 14.04 -- the default browser needs to be changed from Chrome. So, your advice got me to the solution.